# How to show a widget graph in an Activity class

Tags: android, graph, widget

I am a bit new to android development so excuse me about that.
There is an Android Studio project on github: https://github.com/codeka/advbatterygraph
I compiled and installed it on my Nexus 5 and it worked fine. It's a widget which shows a graph with details about battery properties.

I'm trying to show this graph in a Activity class.
I searched a lot and tried to show it using ImageView but couldn't figured it out how to achieve it.

Any help/idea would be much appreciated!
Thanks.